# Race condition in OSX OpenGL setup code

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, opengl, sdl

I'm trying to do OpenGL a rendering in a separate thread on OSX. I'm using SDL to create the window, but I want to write the OpenGL context creation code out by hand. Sometimes it works fine (it should show a green square in a red field), but sometimes it just displays white.

If I run in only one thread (there's a #define below to switch that on and off) everything works fine. If I insert a stall (a for loop counting to 10 million, another #define switch to control that) it works fine, which leads me to believe I have a race condition, and that I need to block the render thread until the OS is done doing whatever it does.

Not being familiar with Cocoa or Objective-C, how do I do that? Or is my problem something else?

Code follows:

```
#include </Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL.h>
#include </Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL_syswm.h>
#include <OpenGL/GL3.h>
#include <array>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <OpenGL/CGLTypes.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <OpenGL/CGLRenderers.h>
#include <thread>

namespace
{
    float const PositionData[] =
    {
        -0.5f,-0.5f,0,   0,0,
         0.5f,-0.5f,0,   0,0,
         0.5f, 0.5f,0,   0,0,
         0.5f, 0.5f,0,   0,0,
        -0.5f, 0.5f,0,   0,0,
        -0.5f,-0.5f,0,   0,0,
    };

    namespace buffer
    {
        enum type
        {
            VERTEX,
            TRANSFORM,
            MATERIAL,
            MAX
        };
    }//namespace buffer
}//namespace

#define RENDER_THREAD
#define BLOCK_RENDER_THREAD

int main() {
    Uint32 init_mode = SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    init_mode |= SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE;
#endif

    SDL_Init(init_mode);

    Uint32 window_mode = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;

    SDL_Window* window;

    if (NULL == (window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500, 500, window_mode))) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_SysWMinfo wmi;
    SDL_VERSION(&wmi.version);

    if (!SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmi) )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::atomic<bool> closing(false);

    auto PollEventQueue = [&closing]() {
        SDL_Event e;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            switch (e.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT: {
                closing = true;
            } break;

            default: {
            } break;
            }
        }
    };

    NSWindow* native_window = wmi.info.cocoa.window;

    auto RenderThreadMain = [native_window, &closing, PollEventQueue]() {
#ifdef BLOCK_RENDER_THREAD
        for (int k = 0; k < 10000000; k++) {}
#endif

        NSOpenGLContext* context;
        @synchronized (native_window) {
            NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixel_format = nullptr;

            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[64] = {
                NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion4_1Core,
                NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 24,
                NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 8,
                NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
                NSOpenGLPFAStencilSize, 8,

                NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
                NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
                NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,

                0
            };

            NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute* the_end = std::find_if(std::begin(attributes), std::end(attributes), [](NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribute) {
                return attribute == 0;
            });

            if (true) {
                NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute multisample_attributes[] = {
                    NSOpenGLPFAMultisample,
                    NSOpenGLPFASampleBuffers, NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(1),
                    NSOpenGLPFASamples, NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute(4),
                    0
                };

                // Copy it onto the attributes array
                int k = 0;
                while (multisample_attributes[k]) {
                    *(the_end++) = multisample_attributes[k++];
                }
            }

            NSView* native_view = [native_window contentView];
            NSRect native_rect = [native_view bounds];

            pixel_format = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
            NSOpenGLView* gl_view = [[NSOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:native_rect pixelFormat:pixel_format];
            [pixel_format release];

            [gl_view setAutoresizingMask:
                (NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewMinXMargin|NSViewMaxXMargin|NSViewMinYMargin|NSViewMaxYMargin)
            ];
            [native_view addSubview:gl_view];

            context = [gl_view openGLContext];

            GLint swap_interval = 1;
            [context setValues:&swap_interval forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];

            [context setView:[native_window contentView]];

            [context makeCurrentContext];
        }

        std::array<GLuint, buffer::MAX> BufferName;
        GLuint ProgramName;
        GLuint VertexArrayName;
        GLint UniformTransform;
        GLint UniformMaterial;

        const char* vertex_shader =
            "#version 150 core\n"
            "in vec3 Position;"
            "in vec2 UV;"
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(Position, 1.0);"
            "}";
        const GLint vertex_shader_length = (GLint)strlen(vertex_shader);

        const char* fragment_shader =
            "#version 150 core\n"
            "out vec4 Color;"
            "void main()"
            "{"
            "   Color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
            "}";
        const GLint fragment_shader_length = (GLint)strlen(fragment_shader);

        GLuint fragment_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource((GLuint)fragment_shader_id, 1, &fragment_shader, &fragment_shader_length);
        glCompileShader((GLuint)fragment_shader_id);

        int shader_compiled;
        glGetShaderiv((GLuint)fragment_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_compiled);
        if (shader_compiled != GL_TRUE) {
            int log_length = 0;
            char log[1024];
            glGetShaderInfoLog((GLuint)fragment_shader_id, 1024, &log_length, log);
            printf("%s", log);
            return 1; // TODO: Error
        }

        GLuint vertex_shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource((GLuint)vertex_shader_id, 1, &vertex_shader, &vertex_shader_length);
        glCompileShader((GLuint)vertex_shader_id);

        glGetShaderiv((GLuint)vertex_shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_compiled);
        if (shader_compiled != GL_TRUE) {
            int log_length = 0;
            char log[1024];
            glGetShaderInfoLog((GLuint)vertex_shader_id, 1024, &log_length, log);
            printf("%s", log);
            return 1; // TODO: Error
        }

        ProgramName = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ProgramName, fragment_shader_id);
        glAttachShader(ProgramName, vertex_shader_id);

        glBindAttribLocation(ProgramName, 0, "Position");
        glLinkProgram(ProgramName);

        glGenBuffers(buffer::MAX, &BufferName[0]);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferName[buffer::VERTEX]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PositionData), PositionData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayName);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayName);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferName[buffer::VERTEX]);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(float), 0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(float), (const GLvoid *)(3*sizeof(float)));

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        while (!closing) {
#ifndef RENDER_THREAD
            PollEventQueue();
#endif

            glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(ProgramName);
            glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayName);
            glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6, 2);

            [context flushBuffer];
            [context update];
        }

        return 0;
    };

#ifdef RENDER_THREAD
    std::thread render_thread = std::thread(RenderThreadMain);

    while (!closing) {
        PollEventQueue();
    }

    render_thread.join();
#else
    RenderThreadMain();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
clang++ test.mm -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework SDL2 -F/Library/Frameworks -std=c++14 -g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should familiarize yourself with Apple's [Thread Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) for Cocoa (especially AppKit). There, you will learn that you shouldn't be manipulating the view hierarchy from a secondary thread. In particular, the call to `-addSubview:` is bad. (Note that the restrictions regarding drawing from background threads described there only apply to conventional drawing. OpenGL does not require that you lock focus on the view.)

Using `@synchronized(native_window)` doesn't do what you think. It only synchronizes with respect to other code which also explicitly uses `@synchronized()` on that same object. It does **not** generally synchronize with anything with just uses or operates on that window. I have no reason to believe that anything in Cocoa does `@synchronized()` on its windows, so you're synchronizing with nothing.

Since the setup of the window and context is one-time work, it should probably just be done on the main thread before the secondary thread is spawned.

Second, you are creating an `NSOpenGLView` and getting the context from that, but then you're telling the context to associate itself with a different view (the window's `contentView`). Why are you doing that? The `NSOpenGLView` owns that context and it should probably remain associated with that view.

Finally, the auto-resizing mask you're using seems odd. Since you're allowing everything to be flexible, the GL view won't keep in sync with the window's content view. It will grow and shrink more slowly, with the margins around it gaining and losing slack as it does. I'm guessing you just want `NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable` so that the views resize together and the margins remain 0.

Comment: "Why are you doing that?" Because I have no idea what I'm doing :P Your comments are much appreciated.

Comment: So I should:

1. Do GL context initialization from the main thread
2. Get rid of @synchronized
3. Create and let die a single NSThread so that Cocoa knows I'm doing multithreaded things and can create mutexes
4. Create a new GL context in the render thread, using the share: parameter
5. Clean up my View stuff and my auto-resizing stuff

Comment: Hmm, actually I seem to have more success creating only one context on the main thread, and then doing [context makeCurrentContext] on the render thread.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2 Yes. 3. Shouldn't be necessary these days but I suppose can't hurt. I suppose you can check `[NSThread isMultiThreaded]` if you're concerned. 4. As you've found, shouldn't be necessary. 5. Yes, depending on exactly what you mean. ;)